# SQL ORDER BY DECODE is sorting number as a string?

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table of flight records created as follows

```
CREATE TABLE FLIGHT_DETAILS
(
FLIGHT_ID           NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
FLIGHT_NO           VARCHAR2(10),
DEPARTURE_DTE       DATE,
TOTAL_PASSENGERS    NUMBER(3)
);
```

I then have a function that my application calls to retrieve the records sorted by the selected column (in descending order).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_get_flight_details (

p_order_col IN CHAR )

RETURN sys_refcursor
AS
    v_ref_cursor    sys_refcursor;
    v_sql_str       VARCHAR2(2048);
BEGIN
OPEN v_ref_cursor FOR

SELECT FLIGHT_NO, DEPARTURE_DTE, TOTAL_PASSENGERS 
FROM FLIGHT_DETAILS
ORDER BY DECODE(p_order_col,
        'FLIGHT_NO', FLIGHT_NO,
        'DEPARTURE_DTE', TO_DATE(DEPARTURE_DTE, 'YYYY/MM/DD'),
        'TOTAL_PASSENGERS', TOTAL_PASSENGERS) DESC;

RETURN v_ref_cursor;
END;
```

Sorting by both `FLIGHT_NO` and `DEPARTURE_DTE` works correctly. My problem comes when I tried to sort by `TOTAL_PASSENGERS`, which got me this

```
FLIGHT_NO   DEPARTURE_DTE   TOTAL_PASSENGERS
-------------------------------------------------
OR3237      01/03/16        9
RM7202      15/01/16        50
CQ8429      05/10/16        250
DA5720      21/07/16        100
```

For some reason, DECODE is sorting the `NUMBER` column as a string. To test, I tried this

```
SELECT FLIGHT_NO, DEPARTURE_DTE, TOTAL_PASSENGERS 
FROM FLIGHT_DETAILS
ORDER BY TOTAL_PASSENGERS DESC;
```

which gave me

```
FLIGHT_NO   DEPARTURE_DTE   TOTAL_PASSENGERS
-------------------------------------------------
CQ8429      05/10/16        250
DA5720      21/07/16        100
RM7202      15/01/16        50
OR3237      01/03/16        9
```

proving that the issue wasn't with the column itself.

Then I tried some solutions I found on SO

```
ORDER BY DECODE(p_order_col,
        'FLIGHT_NO', FLIGHT_NO,
        'DEPARTURE_DTE', TO_DATE(DEPARTURE_DTE, 'YYYY/MM/DD'),
        'TOTAL_PASSENGERS', TO_NUMBER(TOTAL_PASSENGERS)) DESC;


ORDER BY DECODE(p_order_col,
        'FLIGHT_NO', FLIGHT_NO,
        'DEPARTURE_DTE', TO_DATE(DEPARTURE_DTE, 'YYYY/MM/DD'),
        'TOTAL_PASSENGERS', LPAD(TOTAL_PASSENGERS, 10)) DESC;


ORDER BY DECODE(p_order_col,
        'FLIGHT_NO', FLIGHT_NO,
        'DEPARTURE_DTE', TO_DATE(DEPARTURE_DTE, 'YYYY/MM/DD'),
        'TOTAL_PASSENGERS', TOTAL_PASSENGERS*1) DESC;
```

none of which worked (it's still sorted as a string).

So why does `DECODE` refuse to sort a number column as a number? And how do I get it to sort correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `decode()` is an expression and only returns one type.  So, the types have to be converted.

You should use `case` anyway.  My preferred method is multiple statements:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN p_order_col = 'FLIGHT_NO' THEN FLIGHT_NO END),
         (CASE WHEN p_order_col = 'DEPARTURE_DTE' THEN TO_DATE(DEPARTURE_DTE, 'YYYY/MM/DD') END)
         (CASE WHEN p_order_col = 'TOTAL_PASSENGERS' THEN TOTAL_PASSENGERS END) DESC;
```

Each expression sorts by one key.  If the sort key does not match, then the result of the expression is `NULL` -- all rows get the same value, so it doesn't affect the ordering.

Comment: That looks great! Would there not be a performance hit though? Since it looks like you are doing 3 separate sorts instead of 1 (even if 2 of them is always `null`.

Comment: @sml485. See my response in the additional answer.

Comment: @sml485 . . . No, there is no additional performance hit.  Sorting by three keys is pretty much the same as sorting by one key.

Answer (score 1):

There will be little to no performance impact in the example answer posted by Gordon. You are not really doing 3 separate sorts; it's still a singe sort operation. A quick test will show this:

```
select ename, sal, mgr 
from emp 
order by ( case when 'SAL' = 'SAL' then sal end ) 
,        ( case when 'SAL' = 'NAME' then ename end )

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |      |       |       |    21 (100)|          |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY             |      |    14 |   196 |    21  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| EMP  |    14 |   196 |    20   (5)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However I would caution an approach where you try to write a single "generic" SQL statement to handle all sorts of different cases. While this kind of "clever" SQL statement can work functionally, it can be a disaster for performance. It's much better to a have a separate SQL statements. In this example posted here, It would be fairly easy to have three different SQL statements, each with a specific `ORDER BY` clause, and then use a simple `IF THEN ELSE` on the input parameter to determine which SQL statement to run

Comment: Do you mean the performance issue comes with using `case` or `decode`? I get using separate statements depending on input. However my actual table has 9 columns to sort by, with some rather convoluted aggregation/joins lumped inside. I greatly simplified it for this question to highlight the `decode` issue. Splitting them into 9 separate queries sounds like maintenance hell :(

Comment: @sml485. My comment is somewhat general. But I have seen very complex SQL statements, where the developer has tried to be clever, with constructs like:  SELECT * FROM emp WHERE (ename = :1 OR :1 IS NULL) and (job = :2 OR :2 IS NULL). The problem is that the optimizer has no way of determining the selectivity of the predicates, and as a consequence, performance is sub-optimal. So I'm just cautioning the use of the "super generic" SQL statement. Yes, you will have the weigh the cost of maintenance; but I would also suggested that a simpler SQL statement is easier to debug and maintain.